# How to parse html response from fetch() API to iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, response, fetch-api

I am trying to display a web page into an iFrame using fetch() API, where I get the url from the user and then display the page into an iFrame as if it is locally hosted, so that I can use javascript to work on the page from the iFrame without cross-origin issues.

What I am looking for is to get the response redirected into the iframe using srdoc.

Code for html page is below:

```
    <form method="POST">
                        <iframe id="frame" style="resize: both;width: 350px; height:500px;"></iframe>
                        <button type="button" onClick="retrieve()">Retrieve</button>  
                        </form>
                    </div>  
                     <div id="textarea">
                        <textarea id="` + tab_id + `" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your source text here..." rows="20" onchange="change_textarea('` + tab_id + `')" onfocus="set_focus(this)" style="resize: vertical; min-height:35px;" readonly></textarea>
                    </div>  
                </div> 
            </form>
```

This is the javascript function:

```
function retrieve(){
    
    let headers = new Headers();

  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
  headers.append('Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');
  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');
  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    console.log(headers);

    url = document.getElementById("tt").value;
    fetch(url, {
        mode: 'no-cors',
        credentials: 'include',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers
    })
    .then((response) => {
        document.getElementById("frame").srcdoc = response;  
    }) 
}
```

Obviously, with parsing response I don't get the result but just "[Object Response]"; Any suggestions on how to parse the response from fetch API() to the iFrame?

Comment: You recive a JSON, so this JSON has HTML strings?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking...

Comment: `'Content-Type', 'application/json'` is JSON. Where does the `htmlString` come from? `srcdoc` value is a string that represents HTML. When the iframe is rendered, the value of  `srcDoc` is rendered as embedded HTML. So how did you convert `response`, which looks like it should be a JSON, into a `htmlString`?

Comment: I have not converted into htmlString, but it is what I want to do, so that the srcDoc renders the html that I am supposed to parse

Comment: So this JSON looks like HTML or does it look like an Object literal or an Array?

Comment: I don't know because I can't get anything out of the response, but just "[Object Response]"

Comment: In `url = document.getElementById("tt").value;` that `url` can be tested by pasting it to the browser addressbar and then enter key. It should look like an array of objects `[{...}, {...},...]`, or an array `[...]`, or an object `{...}`. It wouldn't even remotely resemble HTML `<...>`

Comment: Ok, I still don't see what I should do...

Comment: Did you do what I said in my last comment? If so what do you see?

Comment: No, because I don't understand what you want me to do.

Comment: What is the `url` at `#tt`?

Comment: Is a url that the user puts into an "input" tag

Comment: Yes copy & paste that url (without quotes " ") into the browser address bar and go to that location (press enter/return, or click the page forward button), then copy & paste what you get from the browser in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
.then((response) => {
    return response.text();  
})
.then((text) => {
    document.getElementById("frame").srcdoc = text;  
})
```